# Selecting output lines in chunk output by modifying the default output hook

Tags: hook, output, knitr

The knitr book, p. 118, \S 12.3.5, has an example of how to suppress long output by modifying
the output chunk hook, but it isn't at all general because it does it globally for all chunks.

I've tried to generalize that, to allow a chunk option, `output.lines`, which, if NULL, has no
effect, but otherwise selects and prints only the first `output.lines` lines.  However, this version
seems to have no effect when I try it, and I can't figure out how to tell why.

More generally, I think this is useful enough to be included in knitr, and would be better if one
could specify a range of lines, e.g., `output.lines=3:15`, as is possible with `echo=`.

```
# get the default output hook
hook_output <- knit_hooks$get("output")

knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
    lines <- options$output.lines
    if (is.null(lines)) {
        hook_output(x, options)  # pass to default hook
    }
    else {
        x <- unlist(stringr::str_split(x, "\n"))
        if (length(x) > lines) {
        # truncate the output, but add ....
        x <- c(head(x, lines), "...\n")
        }
        # paste these lines together
        x <- paste(x, collapse = "\n")
        hook_output(x, options)
    }
})
```

Test case:

```
<<print-painters, output.lines=8>>=
library(MASS)
painters
@
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this solution **does** work.  My actual test example was flawed. Maybe others will find this helpful.